# PHP Linking Files to Root File Directory

Tags: php, file, include, directory, root

I've decided to organize my website into folders, the problem is when I do, the PHP files cannot access /Images in the root directory.  For example: I have a header.php linked to /test_folder/test.php with include.  Neither of these files can access the /Images folder.  Is there a solution that will allow me to organize files into folders and still access main files in the root directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that an initial slash in a pathname will point to the root directory of your file system. Try one of these methods:

```
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "/test_folder/test.php");
```

This if you know the relative path:

```
include("../test_folder/test.php");
```

Comment: Try to do a print_r($_SERVER); to see what variables you have available  to construct a path from.

Comment: [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@localhost [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/Main/coming_soon.php [REMOTE_PORT] => 58400 [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1 [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1 [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET [QUERY_STRING] => [REQUEST_URI] => /Main/coming_soon.php [SCRIPT_NAME] => /Main/coming_soon.php [PHP_SELF] => /Main/coming_soon.php [REQUEST_TIME] => 1382754137 )

Comment: If I can't figure out how to backtrack to the root I can always create a bunch of sub-folders and reformat all the pages.